# Nvidia in ubuntu

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, nvidia-settings

I am using Ubuntu since last year in a very old laptop. Now I'm thinking of switching to a new one.

In my research I found that Ubuntu doesn't come with NVIDIA drivers preinstalled and in some cases Ubuntu doesn't run at all.

Is Ubuntu really that bad with NVIDIA drivers? If no, then how to know which NVIDIA GPU is compatible with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my research I found that Ubuntu doesn't come with NVIDIA drivers preinstalled and in some cases Ubuntu doesn't run at all.
>
> Is Ubuntu really that bad with NVIDIA drivers?

Old and quite inaccurate news.

Since a few releases ago users can select to install Nvidia drivers during the OS installation.

Before that it was just a matter of installing them after the OS.

All GPUs are compatible.